# How to access 50 Milion records using "OR" codition in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, mysql-5.7

I have 300 million data in single partition and now I would to filter that record using or condition on 2 column (index).
is it possible?

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_bulk_tesing` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `request_account` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `responce_account` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `creatition_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `request_account` (`request_account`),
    INDEX `responce_account` (`responce_account`),
    INDEX `creatition_date` (`creatition_date`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=16371
;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `org_account` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

```
select count(temp_bulk_tesing.id) from temp_bulk_tesing
inner join org_account
on (temp_bulk_tesing.request_account=org_account.id
or temp_bulk_tesing.responce_account=org_account.id)
and temp_bulk_tesing.creatition_date >='2019-10-10 22:22:18'
and temp_bulk_tesing.creatition_date <= '2019-10-13 22:22:18'
```

it's taking too much time. how can we optimize that?

Partition also exist in original table but challenge is there we are getting 300 million record in 1 day.

Comment: How many rows in each table now?  I see perhaps 16371 in one table, yet you talk about 300M per day for one of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  select temp_bulk_tesing.id
  from temp_bulk_tesing
  join org_account
    on temp_bulk_tesing.request_account=org_account.id
   and temp_bulk_tesing.creatition_date BETWEEN '2019-10-10 22:22:18'AND'2019-10-13 22:22:18'
  union all
  select temp_bulk_tesing.id
  from temp_bulk_tesing
  join org_account
    on temp_bulk_tesing.responce_account=org_account.id
   and temp_bulk_tesing.creatition_date BETWEEN '2019-10-10 22:22:18'AND'2019-10-13 22:22:18'
) sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure might be a bit tricky to implement but it's worth it.

First slice out the data you going to match with from your big table

```
create temporary table tmp_temp_bulk_tesing
select * from temp_bulk_tesing where creatition_date between '2019-10-10 22:22:18'and 
'2019-10-13 22:22:18';
```

Add a index to make things even faster

```
alter table tmp_temp_bulk_tesing add INDEX ttbt (id);
```

Then do the join

```
select count(temp_bulk_tesing.id) from tmp_temp_bulk_tesing ttbt
inner join org_account oa
on (ttbt.request_account=oa.id or ttbt.responce_account=oa.id)
```

Join is VERY heavy on the database and by slicing out the correct data you can go from hours to seconds or even fractions of a second to process it.

Another trick that might help is to rather then using

```
 and temp_bulk_tesing.creatition_date >='2019-10-10 22:22:18'
 and temp_bulk_tesing.creatition_date <= '2019-10-13 22:22:18'
```

is to first separately get the max and min id from the database and include them into the query.

```
 select max(id), min(id) from temp_bulk_tesing where creatition_date between '2019-10-10 22:22:18' and '2019-10-13 22:22:18'
```

and then use those id's in the query. index in int's should be faster than index on datetimes, and the id's should be in order making it's even easier.

This is not by far as efficient as temporary tables but might be enought for you.

Answer (score 0):

- Do individual COUNTs if that is all you are doing.
- If the row in `org_account` always exists, don't bother with the `JOIN`.
- Use `ON` for how tables are related; use `WHERE` for filtering.
- Make optimal indexes.
- Don't include an extra second.

```
    SELECT 
      ( select COUNT(*)
          from temp_bulk_tesing AS tbt
          join org_account AS oa
            on tbt.request_account = oa.id   -- the only line different
          WHERE tbt.creatition_date >= '2019-10-10 22:22:18'
            and tbt.creatition_date  < '2019-10-10 22:22:18' + INTERVAL 3 DAY
      )
      +
      ( select COUNT(*)
          from temp_bulk_tesing AS tbt
          join org_account AS oa
            on tbt.responce_account = oa.id
          WHERE tbt.creatition_date >= '2019-10-10 22:22:18'
            and tbt.creatition_date  < '2019-10-10 22:22:18' + INTERVAL 3 DAY
      )
```

(It may need `FROM DUAL` at the end.)

And

```
INDEX(request_account, creatition_date),
INDEX(responce_account, creatition_date)
```